# What percentage of Christendom takes early Genesis in a literal sense?

Tags: genesis, literalism, demographics

This obviously varies massively between denominations and even within denominations. I am trying to assess what percentage of Christendom takes early Genesis absolutely literally (six-day creation within the last 10,000 years, Noah's global flood, Adam and Eve as the first humans, etc.) as opposed to allegorically.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview of what this site is about, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Sounds like an interesting question!

Comment: I don't think you're going to get an accurate percentage on this, because any figure would rely on cobbling together disparate surveys with varying definitions and methodologies. Perhaps you could narrow it down to a particular country at least?

Comment: This article says 10% in 2013: http://ncse.com/blog/2013/11/just-how-many-young-earth-creationists-are-there-us-0015164 But it wasn't concerned with all of early Genesis, just creation and evolution.

Comment: 0% take it absolutely literally, because that would of course be completely stupid. A better question would be what percentage think it is historically reliable.

Comment: @curiousdannii: The question makes it specifically clear what the OP means by "literal".

Comment: @Steve: Interesting find, but it's just for the US. If the number is 10% in the US, it's probably well under 1% world-wide. That also seems to be 10% of Americans, not 10% of Christians, which would mean a much higher percentage of US Christians believe that.

Comment: @Flimzy Hardly, the question is asking about historical things, not literal firmaments or heavenly windows.

Comment: @curiousdannii: Huh? Are we reading the same question? `what percentage of Christendom takes early Genesis absolutely literally (six-day creation within the last 10,000 years, Noah's global flood, Adam and Eve as the first humans, etc.)` That pretty clearly spells out what the OP means.

Comment: @Flimzy And I'm just saying that it's wrong to label that literalism.

Comment: @curiousdannii: I'm not sure why you *think* that's wrong, but most people consider that literalism. But whatever your semantic ax you're trying to grind, I don't think it belongs in comments here. The question makes it clear what is being asked, so your comments aren't serving to clarify the question.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some fairly recent data by those not friendly to creationism.

http://www.religioustolerance.org/ev_publid.htm

It looks like those who believe in creationism are 36%. While those who do not believe in evolution are 29%.

It is interesting to note that while falling, the percent change over the generations is not as steep as one might suspect.

There is also a graph where different denominations are polled about their belief in evolution. From Catholic = 58% to Evangelical = 23%

This might give some idea of the distribution.

Comment: It's important to note that this only addresses the US. In the rest of the world, creationism isn't much of a thing.

Comment: The survey also doesn't clarify what it means by "creationism", so it's difficult to know if it aligns perfectly with the OP's question, but it's probably safe to assume it's close.

Comment: I want to know what the 13% of atheists who didn't say evolution was the best explanation believe in. :)

Comment: @ThaddeusB Yes, that caught my eye, too. The grid of the graph fudges it visually by not going to 100%.